# Find an example of a sequence $A_k(1\leqslant k \leqslant n)$ such that its limit does not exists.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $A_k(1\leqslant k \leqslant n)$ be events from sample space $\Omega$.
We say the limit
$\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ exists and equals to the event $B$
whenever for sequences of events $\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k} (n>1)$
and $\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k} (n>1)$
we have:
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k})=B_1=B=B_2=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}).$$
Find an example of a sequence $A_k(1\leqslant k \leqslant n)$ such that its limit does not exists. Prove the claim with details.

I think it should start with finding a sequence $A_k$ and proving $B_1 \neq B_2$ but I don't know how to do it. Could anyone give some more hints?

Comment: Try finding a sequence of events which obviously does not have a limit, perhaps one which oscillates between high and low probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A_k = \Omega$ if $k$ is even and $A_k = \emptyset$ if $k$ is odd. Then $B_1 = \emptyset$ and $B_2 = \Omega$. So the limit does not exist if $\Omega$ is not empty.

Remark: Your $B_1$ is called lim inf of the sequence $(A_k)_k$ and contains exactly the elements, which are in all $A_k$ except for finitely many. Your $B_2$ is called lim sup and contains exactly the elements that are in infinitly many $A_k$.

In that example, any $x \in \Omega$ is contained in infinitely many $A_k$, but there are also infinitly many $A_k$ which do not contain $x$.